# What do you use to sanitize user input with Remix on Cloudflare Pages?

Tags: javascript, cloudflare, remix.run, cloudflare-pages

I was trying to use the package sanitiza-html on my Remix app hosted on Cloudflare Pages without success. Later I understood that the problem is because this package depends on process pollyfill and Cloudflare does not use node as described [HERE](https://github.com/remix-run/remix/issues/1285)

**I would like your suggestion of a safe alternative for sanitization** server side and client side. I'm aware of isomorphic-dompurify but i don't like the fact that it uses [JSDOM](https://github.com/jsdom/jsdom)

Answer (score 1):

I'm going to leave these 2x resources:

- https://github.com/capricorn86/happy-dom
- https://blog.cloudflare.com/introducing-htmlrewriter

I was searching for some Cloudflare stuff and saw this post. My apologies but I've personally NOT used either of the above on Cloudflare, however, Happy-dom is mentioned directly as dependencies of at least 2 (two) Cloudflare-owned Github projects.